# I want to show 2 record per page in Pagination using MySQL LIMIT,

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have to show, showing 2 to 5 in pagination in php. The code I have listed here is working for me. Honesty saying I have altered the source code. Know I want to know. How to bring in echo "showing 1 to 5 in total record of 5" in this code. I don't know how to implement this.

My code goes here:

```
<?php
    $rowstodisplay =2;
    $currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $pid = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['pid'])) 
    { 
        $pid = $_GET['pid']; 
    }
    $startrow = $pid * $rowstodisplay;

    $selectorders=sprintf("SELECT * FROM  parent_cat ORDER BY p_cat ASC");
    $results = mysql_query($selectorders) or die(mysql_error());
    $tot_rsselect = mysql_num_rows($results);

    $query_limit_results = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $selectorders, $startrow, $rowstodisplay);
    $myorderquery = mysql_query($query_limit_results) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalpages = ceil($tot_rsselect/$rowstodisplay)-1;

    $navblock = "";
    if ($pid <= $totalpages) 
        {
        if ($pid > 0) 
        {
            $navblock .= '<a href="'.$currentPage.'?pid=0">First</a> | <a href="'.$currentPage.'?pid='.max(0,$pid-1).'">Previous</a>'; 
        }
        if ( ($pid > 0)&&($pid < $totalpages) ) 
        { 
            $navblock .= " | ";  
        } 
        if ($pid < $totalpages) 
        {
            $navblock .= '<a href="'.$currentPage.'?pid='.min($totalpages, $pid+1).'">Next</a> | <a href="'.$currentPage.'?pid='.$totalpages.'">Last</a>';         
        }
    }
    $nolinks = 15;
    $navpageno = "";
    if ($pid <= $totalpages)
    {
        for($i=max(0,$pid-$nolinks); $i<=min($totalpages, $pid+$nolinks); $i++) 
        {
            $pageno = $i+1;
            if($pid  == $i) 
            { 
                $navpageno .= '<li class="navigation2">'.$pageno.' </li>'; 
            }
            else 
            { 
                $navpageno .= '<li class="navigation"><a href="'.$currentPage.'?pid='.$i.'">'.$pageno.'</a></li>'; 
            }
        }
    } 

    if($navblock != "") 
    {
    ?> 
        <ul class="navigationholder"><?php echo $navpageno; ?></ul> 
    <?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: step 1: format your code.

Comment: http://www.techumber.com/2012/08/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql.html follow this tutorial

Comment: In this tutorial I want to add "showing 1 to 5 in total record of 5" where to do this and how to do

Answer (score 1):

Although the comment was deteled, you wanted to have a quick fix for your question. Unfortunetely I think it's a bad idea to work with deprecated code like `mysql_*`. Therefor I've written a new system for you that will use `PDO` instead. Please do walk through the code and edit where nessesary. I didn't know your column names for example so this code will NOT work on the fly!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagination</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php

        // Database Settings
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = '';
        $dbpass = '';
        $dbname = '';

        // Establish Connection to the Database
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $dbhost .';dbname='. $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass, array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ));

        // Selecting the data from table but with limit
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM parent_cat ORDER BY p_cat ASC LIMIT :start, :page';

        // Prepare query
        $pre = $dbh->prepare($query);

        // Binding values
        $pre->bindParam(':start', $start_from);
        $pre->bindParam(':page', $per_page);

        // Results per page
        $per_page=2;

        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $page=1;
        }

        // Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

        ?>

        <!-- Start building HTML table -->
        <table>

        <?php

        // Execute query
        try {
            $pre->execute();

            // Fetch all results
            $results = $pre->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Loop through results
            foreach($results as $data){

                // Display results in HTML table
                echo "<tr>";

                // Add/Remove your column names here
                echo "<td>". $data['column_name_here'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $data['column_name_here'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $data['column_name_here'] ."</td>";

                // Close HTML table row
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'MySQL query error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        ?>

        <!-- End building HTML table -->
        </table>

        <div>
            <?php

            // Now select all data from table
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM parent_cat';

            // Prepare the query
            $pre = $dbh->prepare($query);

            // Execute the query
            try {
                $pre->execute();

                // Count the results
                $total_records = $pre->rowCount();

                // Keep a record of total number of rows
                $total_rows = $total_records;

                // Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
                $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

                // Going to first page
                echo "<center><a href='pagination.php?page=1'>First Page</a> ";

                // Showing number of pages in between last page
                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){
                    echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=". $i ."'>". $i ."</a> ";
                }

                // Going to last page
                echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=". $total_pages ."'>Last Page</a></center> ";
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'MySQL query error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }

            // Calculate first and last item on current page
            $first = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
            $last = $page * $per_page;

            // Make sure the number can never be more than the total numer of rows
            if($last > $total_rows){
                $last = $total_rows;
            }

            // Showing the results
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<center>Showing ". $first ." to ". $last ." in total record of ". $total_rows ."</center>";

            ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: THanks lot . I think you can do this. can you please help me with this thread for this only I have asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365980/i-want-to-know-how-to-do-multiple-search-with-pagination

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran I don't fully understand what you want exactly with that question. Also I don't see my code anywhere in it and it seems you're still using `mysql_*`, which won't work with my code. Ofcourse I could simply program whatever it is you want, but you're not learning anything from that. You didn't learn anything from my answer over here either. I mean, there's a difference between helping you out and doing your job for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. HI I agree with the thing. If you see my form The values I got form post. they first step I stuck here was get or post for proper pagination. second thing.I have return in if condition, here I want to know how to append in query using in single query. by helping me at least this level sure I will use your code only to achieve pagination. i hope you understand. thanks for your reply for urgent work for me. can you again help me to do this simple work.

Comment: hi can you help alteast to append the query in single query. I will do rest of the work.

Comment: Perhaps you should click on my name and send me an email (it's on my profile). Make sure to zip your entire code and include it as an attachment to the mail. It's almost impossible for me to help you any other way. Also, I should add that I don't understand to much about MySQL. I hardly ever work with JOINS etc.

Comment: ok thanks I will work with and get back to stack. thanks lot.