# I want to know how to do multiple search with pagination

Tags: php

I want to know how to do multiple search with pagination. See total I am giving 200 record. Each page I need to show 20 record. I want the output like this:

1. show 1 to 2o of 200 total record,Next with second page
2. It should shows 21 to 40 of 200.

This is the first time I am doing multiple search with pagination. What I have done so far is, I have given here.

Here is the form:

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pincode"     id="zipsearch"  value='<?php echo $pincode;?>'  class="buttonlengths" placeholder="Search By pincode,Area,State" required/><br/><br/>
<select name="categorypincode" ize="40" class="buttonlengths" />
<option value="">select the subject</option>
<option value="Class I-V Tuition" <?php  if($categorypincode=='Class I-V Tuition') { echo 'selected'; }?>>Class I-V Tuition</option>
<option value="Class VI-VIII Tuition" <?php  if($categorypincode=='Class VI-VIII Tuition') { echo 'selected'; }?>>Class VI-VIII Tuition</option>
<option value="Class IX-X Tuition">Class IX-X Tuition</option>
<option value="Class XI-XII Tuition">Class XI-XII Tuition</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="tutorname" value="<?php echo $tutorname; ?>" class="buttonlengths" placeholder="Search By Tutor Name"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="tbx2"  name="submitpincode" value="Search"/>
</form>


<?php
     $pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
     $categorypincode=$_POST['categorypincode'];
     $tutorname=$_POST['tutorname'];
     if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' &&  $tutorname!='')
    {
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where pincode LIKE '%$pincode%' and classconducted LIKE '%$categorypincode%' and name LIKE '%$tutorname%'");
    }
    else if($pincode!='' &&  $categorypincode!='' )
    {
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where
    pincode LIKE '%$pincode%' and classconducted LIKE '%$categorypincode%'");
    }
    else if($pincode!='')
    {
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  tr.*, t.*  FROM  tinfo  t left join tutorregistration tr  on  tr. tid=t.tsid where
    pincode LIKE '%$pincode%'");
    }
?>


  <div class="middle_cnt">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitpincode']))
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $v=$row['tinfoid'];
    ?>
    <div class="frst_middle">
    <div class="frst_mid_scd">
    <?php  
  echo  '<span class="details">Years of Experience:</span>'.$row['texper'];?><Br/><Br/>
    <?php echo  '<span class="details"> Expertise In:</span>'.$row['texperdetails'];?><Br/><Br/>
    <?php echo   '<span class="details">Teaching Segment.</span>'.$row['commonsegment'];?><br/><Br/>
    <span style="padding-left:300px;" class="details"><a href="tutordetail.php?tid=<?php echo $row['tinfoid'];?>" style="cursor:pointer;">View details</a></span>
    </div><!--end of frst_mid_scd-->
    </div><!--end of frst_middle-->
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
```

I have given the result of my db everything is working for me only the problem is multiple search and pagination.

Comment: Why don't you keep the search variables in pagination link ?

Comment: yes.here search and pagination not done , this is the first time I am doing,I am individual person doing my business . so most of the time I do marketing when have free time I learnt form stack team and their solution

Comment: Implement some pagination there and if problem presist.. attach your pagination code.

Comment: @malay I have done that ,It  could not be completed that one. can you please try at your end.I send the answer for me.

Comment: can any one help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to do pagination. I am having 200 record in db. Each page I need to show 20 record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374790/i-want-to-do-pagination-i-am-having-200-record-in-db-each-page-i-need-to-show)

Comment: please look over the answer and do the needful. that is great for future visitor